# How to solve Nullpoint in android

Tags: android-activity

This is the code in MainActivity
MainActivity.java:541

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("mCurrentChapter", mCurrentChapter);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("index", mPager.getCurrentItem());
    ////Log.e("SaveInstance", mCurrentChapter + " " + mPager.getCurrentItem());
}
```

I don't see any problem.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.techexpert4u.duaaadhkaar.MainActivity.onSaveInstanceState(MainActivity.java:541)
            at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1153)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1223)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3234)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1223)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)

        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting. And surely you see a problem since there is an exception. Debug the code.

Comment: Looks like some of the variables that you are referring to in that function is NULL. Step through the code to figure out which variable it is or just look at the variable on the line 541.

Comment: this is the code in 541@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("mCurrentChapter", mCurrentChapter);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("index", mPager.getCurrentItem());
    ////Log.e("SaveInstance", mCurrentChapter + " " + mPager.getCurrentItem());
}

Comment: You just copy pasted the entire function again! Check what is on line 541. If you are not able to figure that out, I am afraid no one here will be able to help you..

Comment: that is the code for line 541